# Django get last value for each forgin key values

Tags: python, django, filter

**In models.py**

```
class loan(models.Model):
    completed=models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,null=True)
    application_id=models.CharField(max_length=100,unique=True)

class topay(models.Model):
    loanapplication=models.ForeignKey(loan,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    paymentdate=models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
```

How to get last paymentdate for every loan application
**In views.py**

```
topay.objects.filter().values().annotate(last=Max('paymentdate'))
```

Comment: you can define a model method/property which is more convenient than annotation. Also The model definition is a class, so always use CapWords convention (no underscores).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to get each `loan` latest `topay` you can filter like this

```
loan.objects.annotate(
    maxpaydate=Max("topay__paymentdate"),
).values("id", "maxpaydate")
```

Comment: Yes, Its Working